# how to detect if a binary image exist in src with php?

Tags: php

there I have some img tags ..I want read content of their src.

in some src I have binery code instead normal src like this:

```
 data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAA0JCgsKCA0LCgsODg0PEyAVExISEyccHhcgLikxMC4pLSwzOko+MzZGNywtQFdBRkxOUlNSMj5aYVpQYEpRUk//2wBDAQ4ODhMREyYVFSZPNS01T09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT0//wAARCAIRA6wDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL...
```

Is there any way I detect if it is binary image?

I try this:

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime = finfo_file($finfo, $fileDIR);
finfo_close($finfo);
```

but it return image/jpeg ...

Answer (score 1):

If I got your problem right, you want to be able to distinguish between something like

- `<img src="path/to/myimage.jpg" />`

and

- `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4A..." />`

when analysing a HTML file using PHP, is this correct?

If so, you could look at the contents of the `src` attribute of the `img` and find out whether it starts with "`data:`". If (and only if) this is the case, you can assume that a binary image follows, see details [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Format).

So, if you stumble upon a `data:` at the beginning of the `src` content, you can get the image by parsing the rest of it (possible regarding the base64 encoding and/or charset given, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Format) again). Else, you can access the image "normally" by the link in the `src`.